# Nissan Sentra- automatic, stalls and jerks

Tags: nissan

I have been searching for answers, and problems like mine, and it seems that it may be easier to describe my problem to you (the experts?).

1)My car has begun 'stalling' when I first turn the ignition, it takes a few times for it to roll over and turn on- this happens almost every time.
2) When driving down the highway, my car will jerk, as if it were tied to a rope from behind attached to something sturdy that had no slack left. It sort of pulls, while going 100+ kph - in a way that seems as if it is trying to shift gears but is not transitioning well to the next one- my car is an automatic. This continues sporadically, sometimes every minute, or 5 or 10, sometimes never.
3) When starting her up, I let it sit for at least ten minutes while it sputters, which usually helps but sometimes it doesn't and the car will do the jerking thing for 10 minutes after starting up, or when going up hill.

What could these things be? I've checked into it being a faulty knock sensor and had that replaced last year. I've learned that it could be a fuel injector problem, a fuel filter problem, spark plugs, transmission problems? I want to have some kind of idea before taking it into the shop.
Thank you, folks!

Comment: When it jerks, do the RPMs change?

Comment: Any engine codes? Lights on the dashboard? Have you checked the fluid level in the transmission?